# star and bars with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Bob, Bill, and Joe have 42 identical candies. How many ways can they split these candies among the 3 of them so that none of them have 0 candies and Bob and Bill  have the same amount of candies.?

I made this problem up myself and I can't figure out how to deal with the 0 candy restriction

Edit: I forgot a part

Comment: One way of seeing this would be to consider the number of non-negative integer solutions to
$$
x_1 +2x_2 = 39
$$

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy if you think about it. Bob and Bill can each get either $1$ candy, or $2$, or $3$, and so on till $20$ candies. Note that if they each get $21$, then there are no candies left for Joe. There are a total of $\mathbf{20}$ ways.

Answer (score 0):

Give each of them 1 candy each. Now out of the 39 candies left if select any odd number of candies and give it to Joe. Now an even number of candies are left , distribute them equally among Bill and Bob.